# Retrieve google user info using php client library

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

Actually I used javascript client for retrieve user profile information. so I used following api call

```
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
 var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
   'userId': 'me'
 });
 request.execute(function(resp) {     
 });
});
```

so this work fine and I retrieved user details. but now I need to retrieve that logged user details using php. I used google-php-client-lib this is my code

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('xxx');
    $client->setClientSecret('xxx');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('xxx');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));

    try{
        $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
        return $person = $plus->people->get('me');
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e){
        error_log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'.$e->getMessage());
    }
```

but this returns following exception

> Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?key=xxx: (401) Invalid Credentials. actually I used same credentials which I used to javascript. please help me. what is the mistake I did ?

Comment: It looks like you've omitted some information from your question. How are you doing auth in the first case? Are you using the Google+ Sign-In button, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In my code I just pass clientId and clientSecret to the Google_Client, but not developerKey.
Maybe that's the problem?

Even in their official example they dont use developer key, see [FileUploadExample](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/fileupload.php)